# Кастомная сортировка массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Приходит массив с данными -  [JavaScript, Python, C++, Java, PHP, HTML, CSS]. Нужно сделать сортировку массива, чтоб на выходе получить [Javascript, CSS, HTML, Java, Python, C++]. Никак не могу сделать алгоритм, чтоб дополнительно не присваивать каждому элементу цифровой индекс и сортировать их просто по числам.

Comment: Почему именно так сортирует? Используйте `sort` - он принимает функцию сортировки.

Comment: Нужно именно в таком порядке. Sort сортирует по алфавиту или по порядку чисел, но вот, как сделать, чтоб сортировка была именно такой - вопрос.

Comment: Судя по текущему описанию проблемы, вам вполне подойдет такой вариант: `function mySort(arr) {return ['Javascript', 'CSS', 'HTML', 'Java', 'Python', 'C++'];}` Если не подойдет, то конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Приходит массив с данными в любом порядке. При клике данные в массиве сортируются в "правильном" порядке. "Правильный" - указанный в задании.

Comment: 1) Задание, значит звонкая монета на кошель. Тут только вопросы. 2) Порядок всё так же неясен. Если нужно сортировать **именно эти** значения - подменяйте на уже сохранённую константу с правильным порядком, дабы не парится.

Comment: Данных может прийти и больше: три CSS или четыре C++. Это будет таблица людей и их нужно отсортировать по языкам. В данной таблице приоритет языков именно такой. Условно, можно заменить эти данные на [second, fourth, first, fifth, sixth, third], а отсортировать нужно [first,second,third, fourth...]

Comment: Алгоритм-то какой? Закономерности особой не вижу.

Comment: Да, тогда буду присваивать каждому числовой индекс и сортировать их по числам. Спасибо всем за участие.

Comment: @Other, есть массив элементов с некоторым ключом. По этому ключу требуется выполнить сортировку, но не лексикографическую, а по заранее заданному порядку ключей.

Answer (score 1):

Вот эффективный алгоритм в синтаксисе ES6.

Вывод смотреть в браузерной консоли, открыв её до запуска скрипта.

```js
var order = ["JavaScript", "Python", "C++", "Java", "PHP", "HTML", "CSS"];

var data = [];

for (var q=0; q<10; ++q) {
  data.push({lang: order[Math.random()*order.length|0], val: q})
}

console.table(data)

function orderData(data, order) {
  var temp = Object.create(null), res = [];
  
  order = [].concat(order);

  for (var key of order) {
    temp[key] = [];
  }

  for (var x of data) {
    if (!temp[x.lang]) {
      order.push(x.lang);
      temp[x.lang] = [];
    }

    temp[x.lang].push(x);
  }

  for (var key of order) {
    //temp[key].sort(выполнить сортировку по дополнительным параметрам)
    res.push(...temp[key]);
  }

  return res;
}

console.table(orderData(data, order));
console.table(orderData([{lang: 'new', val: -1}].concat(data), order));

console.log(order);
```

Comment: а в чем смысл строки `order = [].concat(order);`? перезаписать глобальную переменную на новую себя же?

Comment: @Grundy, чтобы сделать опию. Хотя, [надо было делать slice](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550998/178988) :)

Comment: Ты просто ее себе же присваиваешь, и как-то смысл в копии теряется :-)

Comment: @Grundy, неа: `order.push(x.lang);` Смысл копии - не портить массив у вызывающего кода.

Comment: Но сейчас ты его портишь :-) ты же присваиваешь копию - **той же самой** глобальной переменной

Comment: @Grundy, я аргумент у функции пропустил... Исправил.